# Increase preview quality in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am using brushes with small particles that look as desired when zoomed in, but they collapse in a huge blob of paint when they are zoomed out. I tried "View > Preview on CPU" and that makes it better than "Preview on GPU", but still way too much.

When the image is exported to raster and scaled down in Photoshop the amount of color is the expected one, therefore it's just Illustrator's preview being too low quality.

Is there a way to increase the quality of the preview?

Answer (score 3):

## No.

The preview, whatever it is in terms of quality, is baked into the application and dependent upon the quality of your graphic card and the pixel density of your monitor.

Comment: That's a bummer. CPU resize should be the same for everybody, though,and that's not accurate also. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Wes there is a huge error in the way that all major vendors render vector graphics. The GPU renderong engine is actually better (when it works) and a huge step towards rendering vector graphics correctly.

Comment: But that's still entirely in teh hands of Adobe. There's nothing the user can do other than to tell the app to use the GPU. And.. if the GPU isn't wonderful, well....

Comment: I have a kinda high end GPU... if that's not good, then most of GPUs gotta be not good...

Comment: @Wes Whats kinda high end gpu and what os. Anyway the sample amount is fixed not much you can do abut that. At least the gpu makes for linear blending.

Comment: well maybe it's not high end anymore, but it's not horrible yet: RX580 on windows 10

Comment: The pixel density of the display will *really* alter preview quality. The best GPU in the world is still limited to using the pixel density of the display. You need a retina, 4k, 5k display, to really see much improvement.

Comment: i don't need a retina display when i scale the image in photoshop

Comment: But Photoshop is a raster to raster output. Illustrator is vector to raster. The preview is rasterized on-the-fly for Illustrator, it's not for Photoshop. That's why working in Outline mode in AI is 500000% faster.. no on-the-fly rasterizing for previews. I'm **not** a developer, but this has always been my understanding.

Comment: but surely they can do better than that. in fact, out of curiosity i checked the same image in inkscape and it's noticeably better (but still wrong compared to PS and also veeeery slow).

Comment: AI is a behemoth.. it took them 3 extra years to get it to 64-bit aware... took them 4 extra years to even add the GPU preview. From what I understand, it's so old and the code base is so riddled with "patches" from the past 30 years that in order to effectively fix something, like the horrible redraw speeds, or that hidden "object limit" one can reach, the app would need a ground up rebuild. And financially Adobe's not interested in that. It's not their flagship product like Photoshop.Adobe is more willing to invest dev time (and expense) in PS because of that.

Comment: Remember they built AI on a postscript base for the Mac... then ported it to Windows.. At v9 I believe.. build on a postscript base for Windows and ported that to the Mac.. then at v10 built on a PDF base and ported to both. No clue what they are doing with CC now, but I can tell you any CC version does not run as snappy and briskly as CS6 does here. At least until you hit that "maximum object limitation"

Comment: @wes its a tradeof id they  render it  better then you will feel the software slow down. Even photoshop does not do the best possible recostruction of the supersampled image. You can do a lot better.

Comment: it should be customizable @joojaa

Comment: @Wes Maybe, but people do not become happy with more controls. In fact a lot of people seem to become positively unhappy with too much options (this is one of the big secrets of apple, which they have used efficiently at several times). What if i want to use floating point color? Or long double precision canvas? NURBS curves? Triangular coons patches? No, they can simply nt veer too much off from how the corresponding display systems in pdf readers, web browsers work and splitting up the experience between different user groups is not good for Adobe. No matter how much you want stuff.